# Apache Cordova for android do not load resources

Tags: android, cordova, angular

I have created an Angular 2 application and I'm looking for creating an Android application with Apache Cordova. When I load the application in a Marshmallow emulator, the application does not load any of the declared resources. If I use the browser plugin it works as expected. Using Chrome to inspect the device's console reveals the following output.

**Chrome console output:**

[image: console]

If I run the Cordova initial sample it works in the same Android emulator so it has to be a problem with the sources. The code can be checked in the [Github repository](https://github.com/becompany/angular2-rss-reader-tutorial/tree/cordova-integration). The application is in the **www** directory, for testing it is necessary to add the *android* platform.

```
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova run android
```

I can not found an answer for this problem:

- The resources looks fine - discard file path issues.
- The browser plugin works (Chrome) - discard application errors and security policies.
- The cordova sample works as expected for Android - discard environment errors.

Please, does anyone knows what is the problem with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the root cause. The problem is that by using the `angular-cli` tool, the tag `<base href="/">` is being added automatically. According to the [tag documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base), it serves a base to resolve all the document's relative URLs.

For this use case, removing the base tag or configuring it to a valid value like `<base href="/android_asset/www/">` fixes the problems. As I do not use routing features (yet) I feel more confortable removing it or setting a value like `<base href="."/>` that it's suitable for more platforms builds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying Content-Security-Policy? 
Or how about modifying 'allow-intent' in config.xml?
When I was having resources issue, these were helping.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @hgoon. Unfortunately that did not help. All my resources are loaded locally and following the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) documentation I have tried by adding:

`<allow-intent href="*" />`