# How to use javascript files from angular 2 (angular-cli) project in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, angular-cli

When I build my angular-cli project it generates a number of bundle.js files that I want to use in my cordova project. The problem is that cordova doesn't read the js files. The js files is in the www folder and script tags in the index.html file.
Does anyone know why cordova doesn't read the js files?

This is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <base href="/">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <test-app>
            <div class="center-div center-text">
                Loading... <br /><br />
                <!--<img class="loading no-style" src="/images/loading.png">-->
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
        </test-app>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** This solution is working for me:

Add this to the config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
```

And then change the base href from `<base href="/">` to `<base href=".">`

Comment: May you have a look at ionic which also provides angular support for cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not comment (not enough reputation) but I had the same problem and found the solution already here in Stackoverflow. As there's no voted answer and there is no explanation about your conclusions I leave the link to my explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707190/6852181

Please note that you can declare the base path when using the angular-cli tool by using the parameter `--base-href PATH`. This way you do not have to manually update anything, you can use `--base-href .` when building.

Salu2.

Comment: Yes, it works for me now. Look at the edit in my post to see which solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli is using webpack for DM and it counterfeits your file structure so for specific problem you can go through very good tutorial for cordova users at https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/tech/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2.html or you can use systemjs and gulp for conventional way